# Acer Nitro 5 Ram Almost Full Everytime with no Application running

Tags: windows-10, memory, task-manager

I have an Acer Nitro 5 Ryzen 5 Laptop and it have 8 GB of RAM out of which 2.1 GB is hardware reserved for Graphics I think. Rest ~5.8 GB left is always under use and only about 100MB ram is free.
No software is open now. and see the screenshot.

[image: This is a screenshot of Task Manager Showing Memory USAGE]

[image: This Image shows the task running and the task eating more ram]

It only shows that windows defender is using almost 200 mb rest apps are using 2-15 MB (top 50 apps) each which sums to cost around 500mb and where the rest memory are gone?

Anyone having any idea.
My windows is up to date. With all drivers updated. I solve this problem by restarting the laptop but after sometime it again happens.

Comment: Check what's under those > reveal arrows to the left in your 2nd pic. They indicate there are sub processes which are not included in the visible totals.

Comment: The sub process are services or sub task whose total memory sums up to give the same memory usage which is shown in picture 2. After 2nd last update this problem is happening.

Comment: What happens to memory allocation when you start running processes? Ideally, Defender will give back the memory it's using as cache so that your real applications can run. Remember, unused memory is wasted memory

Comment: Ideally it should free the memory but it is not happening. and I have to regularly restart my laptop to free some memory because task manager do not show any process which is eating memory so that I can kill it, but after restarting and using it for a while, the ram again gets filled. So I installed Avast Free Antivirus, and Now everything is fixed. The problem started with a Windows Update. Also task manager is not giving any information that which process is eating the ram. As you can see in the pictures.

Comment: If there's no process using memory then it's the kernel (Windows itself). This is a caching thing, and the memory should be given up to applications on demand. Are you really sure it isn't?

Comment: Ya I am very sure, there is some problem in Windows Defender and Task Manager. I have been facing this problem since 2 months and now although after having 8 gb ram and ssd i was not even able to open sublime text editor. So I decided to install any antivirus so that defender is switched off. You can google it lot of people are facing the same issue of defender eating more ram.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
Actually when I bought this laptop I got Norton Antivirus for 30 days. After that I did not renew it So it expired. After some days I removed Norton Antivirus.
And after removal of Norton Antivirus, Windows Defender came into action to take over the charge to protect my PC.

But the guys at Microsoft did not gave time and attention towards memory management and memory leaks in Windows defender. and windows defender starts to Eat all my Ram.

**My laptop have 8 gb ram out of which 3 gb is hardware reserved and rest 5 gb left out of which 3.5 gb used by windows defender and 1 gb by searchui.exe by cortana and rest 500 mb by other background services.**

Also I have have recently turned on my search Indexing so no more space left. **and the main problem is when I open Task Manager to check which process is using more ram. Noting shows up. So i used third party task / process manager to find out the msmpeng.exe and searchui.exe are using almost all ram.**

I also disabled windows defender but nothing happened. I also turned off all scheduled scans which are automatically scheduled by default using windows task scheduler But this also did not helped at all.

**So now it was the time to take charge from windows defender So I installed Avast Free Antivirus and now everything is fine. Now every time my ram usage is less than ~60%**

[Screenshot of taskmanager now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iefU.png)